# python why two different methods find and index

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I understand the working of the find and index methods -

```
str = "this is bad"
str.find("good")
-1
str.index("good")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
```

But what is the rationale behind having two functions for the same task?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20410998/4966987) as a good answer and understood that with

`find() - if the string isn't found, -1 that is returned is the same as the index of the last character in the string as so would create confusion`

`index() - the try-catch that would have to be used would create an overhead for a fast operation`

or am I getting this wrong?

Also, why if that the case, the `find()` method can only be used with strings?
Surely, the overhead using `index()` is the same whether you use it on lists or strings? Or is it because lists tend to be generally bigger in size than strings?

Comment: Yes, you have that right. As for your other question, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848954/python-why-lists-do-not-have-a-find-method).

Comment: Is there something in particular you didn't find satisfying about the answer you cite? I thought it was pretty good. (I can't answer your last question, however.)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Could you point out in that question, what you think is the correct reason fo not having `find()` for lists? The most upvoted answer seems to give alternatives but not the reason.Thanks.

Comment: @Sophologist No as I said, the answer was good and helped me understand the reason for `find()` to have been introduced later on.I cited it to ask why the same rationale wasn't being used for lists

Comment: I'm not sure there _is_ a correct reason, as you can see from the other answers there. Sometimes a feature doesn't get implemented because it just doesn't seem necessary enough. Maybe a fast search for a possibly absent substring is a common use case for strings, but lists are generally searched for objects that are guaranteed to be present. I don't know.

Comment: Maybe the source code implementation was totally different so they didn't feel like giving same name for two different classes' methods ?

Comment: @Rockybilly Ya looks like the answer is simple semantics rather than technical. Unless, someone has knows a technical reason.