# Which is faster between s.find() and s.index()

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Now that I understand the difference between `s.find()` and `s.index()` in Python thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410385/python-why-do-the-find-and-index-methods-work-differently), I am wondering, which method is faster?

Is there any significant difference in term of speed other than potential overheads if we have to enclose `s.index()` within a `try/except`?

Comment: In terms of *time complexity* (big oh) the two are equivalent.

Comment: I understand they probably use a similar - if not identical - algorithm and differ only in their output, but I was just wondering if there was a noticeable performance difference.

Comment: If you want to know what's faster `timeit`!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any significant difference in term of speed other than potential overheads if we have to enclose `s.index()` within a `try/except`.

In (C)Python at least, `find`, `index`, `rfind`, `rindex` are all wrappers around an internal function [`any_find_slice`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cb90f261226fc2d4db60a68b53a788e8ae5905cf/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9222).

The implementation is the same. The only difference is that `index` and `rindex` will raise a `ValueError` for you if it finds that the result of calling `any_find_slice` is `-1`.

If you went ahead and timed these you'd see how there's clearly no meaningful difference between them:

```
➜  ~ python -m perf timeit -s "s = 'a' * 1000 + 'b'" "s.find('b')"
Median +- std dev: 399 ns +- 7 ns
➜  ~ python -m perf timeit -s "s = 'a' * 1000 + 'b'" "s.index('b')"
Median +- std dev: 396 ns +- 3 ns
```

I'm using [`perf`](https://github.com/haypo/perf) for the timings here.

I'm guessing in other implementations of Python *this shouldn't differ*. Both methods do the same thing and differ only in how they react when the requested element was not found.

Comment: Thanks, so they are indeed the very same function internally. So I guess there should not be any noticeable speed/performance difference then...

Comment: @YeO you generally need to guard against exceptions thrown with `str.index` but that's the only thing that would make it slower. Besides that, they do the same thing.

Comment: Just wanted to add that in both these profiles, the substring is found, so there is no substantial difference. When the substring is NOT found, then you have a big difference between the two (index being a lot slower).

Answer (score 1):

@Dimitris's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42551760/4421959) showed that `s.find()` and `s.index()` perform equally well *if the substring is found*.

But as @augustomen [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551556/which-is-faster-between-s-find-and-s-index#comment111850740_42551760), if the substring is not found then `s.index()` will be significantly slower due to the exception handling. We can test this with the following code snippets.

Note that I'm using a different machine to @Dimitris so my timings cannot be compared with his.

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s "s = 'a' * 1000" "s.find('b')"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 87.3 nsec per loop
```

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s "s = 'a' * 1000" "try: s.index('b')" "except ValueError: pass"
1000000 loops, best of 5: 242 nsec per loop
```

It's clear that `s.find()` is the winner when the substring is not found, but is that just because we didn't include a `try`/`except` block for it?

Let's try adding a `try`/`except` block to `s.find()` (even though we know it won't be triggered).

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s "s = 'a' * 1000" "try: s.find('b')" "except ValueError: pass"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 89.1 nsec per loop
```

We see here that the mere presence of a `try`/`except` block barely alters the time at all. It's only when the exception is actually triggered that we incur a meaningful hit to performance.

The moral of the story is to use `s.find()` if there's a reasonable chance that the substring won't be found.

If you're sure that the substring will almost always be found then you can use either `s.find()` or `s.index()`. You might prefer `s.index()` in that case, because the `try`/`except` syntax signals to other developers that you are handling an edge case that you don't expect will occur very often.